# Unable to create beans for testing using @ContextConfiguration in junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to write junit test cases for my application.After using Junit 5, I am unable to create the necessary beans by using @ContextConfiguration.

It didn't throw any error. But while Autowiring the beans in the testing class I got null values

I have added the following dependencies

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0"
testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.0')
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0"
```

and my code

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceTestContextConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationConfigTest {

@Autowired
private ApplicationServiceConfiguration
```

applicationServiceConfiguration;

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class ServiceTestContextConfiguration {
@Bean
public ApplicationServiceConfiguration applicationServiceConfiguration() {
    return new ApplicationServiceConfiguration();
}
```

i am using spring-boot 2.

Comment: Mark your ServiceTestContextConfiguration class @Configuration then check

Comment: I tried with @Configuration, But it is also not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be we mixed the imports of junit4 with junit5. Let's annotate the configuration class with `@Configuration` (`org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;`).

In the main unit test, let's use the following,

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceTestContextConfiguration.class)
```

Instead of `@Before`, use `@BeforeEach` and make sure all imports are from junit5 (including assertions)

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

Comment: very useful one